# Flex ítem crece en altura sin razón alguna en internet explorer 11 cuando tiene un elemento img como hijo

Tags: html, css

**Comienzo update**

El problema se resuelve agregando el siguiente CSS a flex-item-1

```
flex-shrink: 0;
```

Pero aun necesito saber el por qué de este comportamiento, flex-shrink lo que hace es reducir el tamaño de un flex-item si el contenedor flex lo requiere, entonces para mi no tiene sentido de que flex-shrink este causando que el flex-item crezca

**Fin update**

Tengo un contenedor con dos flex-items, uno tiene texto y el otro tiene una imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En navegadores modernos los elementos se renderizan bien, pero en internet explorer 11 el flex-item que tiene la imagen crece sin razón alguna

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .flex-container{
                display: flex;
                width: 300px;
                background-color: teal;
                color: #fff;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            img{
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
            }

.flex-item-1{
  background-color: orange;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="flex-item-1">
              <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWgCz.jpg" alt="Image">
            </div>
           <div class="flex-item-2">
              <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis est architecto neque soluta voluptates eius natus nobis. Eum exercitationem hic sit voluptatum soluta, incidunt, dolorum debitis asperiores esse magnam iusto.</p>
           </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

A continuacion adjunto imagen de como se ve en internet explorer 11, flex-item-1 es el que tiene color de fondo naranja, si se fijan esta tomando mas espacio del que debería, flex-basis es auto y debería su altura ajustarse a su contenido el cual es la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Porque ocurre esto en internet explorer 11?

Ocurre cuando tengo una imagen como contenido porque si agrego un parrafo la altura del flex-item, la altura es calculada correctamente (Se ajusta a su contenido)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

A partir de Internet Explorer 10 aparentemente hubo un bug que hacía que el flex-shrink tenga como valor inicial 0 o none, en lugar de 1 como sucede con otros navegadores.

Esto lo puedes ver en la siguiente documentación dando click sobre la estrella de Internet Explorer:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink

Por otro lado hay una serie de bugs listados en el siguiente link (Viene del anterior):
https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#6-the-default-flex-value-has-changed

Creo que en tu caso se aplica el Bug #3 que básicamente especifica bugs que afectan a IE10 e IE11, en los que tienen problemas para reconocer un `height` de un padre o elemento, y sugiere como solución aplicar un `min-height`, podés probarlo incluso con un valor de `10px` funciona ya que es el alto mínimo.
Yo hice esta prueba y funcionó ok, tanto en IE como en Chrome.

```
      .flex-item-1 {
        min-height: 10px;
        background-color: orange;
      }
```

Digo que debe ser el bug #3, porque el único que habla de `flex-shrink` indica que fue resuelto en Internet Explorer 11 (Quizás te falte alguna actualización sino).

Esto es lo que dice inicialmente el Bug#3:
"En IE 10-11, las declaraciones de altura mínima en contenedores flexibles funcionan para dimensionar los contenedores en sí, pero sus elementos secundarios flexibles no parecen conocer el tamaño de sus padres. Actúan como si no se hubiera establecido ninguna altura."

Los otros bugs no los identifiqué con tu caso, pero quizás encuentres allí otra información útil.

En cuanto al comportamiento al poner `flex-shrink: 0;`
Es que le estás asignando un `flex-shrink` que IE no tiene por defecto, entonces ajusta el contenido o calcula en realidad. Considerando que 0 en IE es el valor por defecto, como el 1 lo es en otros navegadores.

En cuanto al por qué sucede con la imágen y no con el párrafo, en uno de los bugs indica que al no poder identificar un `height` de padre o elemento, toma como `height` para el cálculo el tamaño original del elemento que está adentro, así que el tamaño original de la imagen podría estar determinando esa diferencia en la altura.

Esto último haría que tenga sentido ponerle un `min-height` al padre para solucionar el `height` no reconocido, de esta forma el padre se ajustaría y el cálculo lo haría sobre el padre y no sobre el tamaño de la imágen, ajustando la imágen correctamente al final.

Para finalizar, el bug #12 explica que los elementos `inline` en IE10 e IE11 no son tratados como `flex-items`, los elementos `<p>` son del tipo bloque, lo cual también sugiere una diferencia de comportamiento. De todos modos no olvidemos que el `<P>` o un `<span>` incluso no tienen width y height como si tienen las imágenes, que muchas veces es mayor de lo que finalmente mostramos.

Comment: Bastante completa tu respuesta, tan solo una mínima duda: ¿es _windows 10_ y no _IE 10_?

Comment: Perdón, es Internet Explorer 10, ya lo modifiqué! Incluso las pruebas las hice en un PC con windows 7 y uno con Windows 10 sin problemas. Muchas gracias, si no me preguntabas no lo notaba.. Lo escribí como a las 4 am, estaba Zombie, pero traté de dejar la mayor cantidad posible de info.